# FQL app access tokens

Tags: php, facebook-fql

Note: App access tokens are being used here so there is no login or permissions required.

My app access token is valid according to the Facebook App access token debugger
My FQL request is correct according to the Graph API explorer (for FQL)

However when I attempt a FQL search using my app access token:

```
$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.'fql?q='.urlencode($fql_query) . '&access_token=' . urlencode($acctoken);
```

I get the response:

{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }
}

The code I'm using literally worked two days ago but not it appears to be broken.

Does anyone know what is going on? I've looking into the app access token depreciation after 60 days but surely this would appear as an invalid token in the Facebook access token debugger. Also isn't the error message different if the app access token is depreciated.